# TreeMap - Search Time Complexity

Tags: java, search, insert, time-complexity, treemap

What is the time complexity of a get() and put() in a TreeMap?

Is the implementation same as a Red-Black Tree?

Comment: Poor questions.  The answers are in the TreeMap javadocs, plain to see.  All you needed to do was read them.

Comment: But Google finds this post first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459259/why-treemap-takes-ologn-time-in-get-put

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

> This implementation provides
>   guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove
>   operations

Answer (score 11):

TreeMap is:

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation.
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove  operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.