# Why treemap takes O(log(n)) time in Get/put

Tags: java, treemap

In one of the posts I saw that `TreeMap` takes  `O(log(n))` time for get/put.
Can someone please answer why it takes `O(log(n))`, even when it can search directly through get/put using key?

Comment: How many operations do you think it takes to search directly?

Comment: You should check the algorithms in the book that are referred by the Javadoc of the Treemap class, instead of asking here in an inappropriate format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a TreeMap, the key/value entries are stored in a Red-Black tree, and in order to find if a key is contained in the tree, you have to traverse it from the root, down some path, until reaching the required key or reaching a leaf.

A tree containing n elements has an `O(log n)` height, and therefore that's the time it would take to search for a key.

Comment: but the op asked why O(log(n))?

Comment: @KickButtowski I had a typo in my original version. Fixed now.

Comment: I think it does not hurt to say red black tree which is kind of **balanced tree**