# Divide a Set into Subsets of objects having equal field?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, data-structures, treemap

I am currently trying to implement a data structure in java, and would like to divide a set of input objects, into different subsets of objects having an equal field.

`An example use case`:

We want to divide a list of persons to sub list of persons being born a certain date.

`Input`: person1 born 1990, person2 born 2000, person3 born 1990.

`Output`:

1 -> person1, person3

2 -> person2

```
public Map<Integer, List<Foo>> getIntToFooMap(List<Foo> foos) { 
    Map<Integer, List<Foo>> map = new TreeMap<>(); // need keys to be automatically ordered.
    List<Foo> foosWithSameSetId = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!foos.isEmpty) { 
       for (Foo foo: foos) {
           for (Foo foo2: foos) {
               if (foo.getSetId().equals(foo2.getSetId())) {
                   foosWithSameSetId.add(foo2);
               }
           }
        map.put(foo.getSetId(), foosWithSameSetId);
        foosWithSameSetId.clear();
       }
    }
  return map;
 }
```

The code above is not optimal, the time complexity is quadratic, and also not thread safe.
Can someone tell me of a better way to divide a List or a Set into subsets of objects having an equal field, in this case the `setId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no need for the nested loop. You'd just get or create the set of the current `foo`'s `setId`, and add `foo` to it:

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(foo.getSetId(), i -> new ArrayList<>()).add(foo);
}
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    List<Foo> list = map.get(foo.getSetId());
    if(null == list) list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(foo);
}
```

Now, you need to keep in mind the time [complexity for your map implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864204/treemap-search-time-complexity).

As an alternative, a `groupingBy` stream collector would add brevity to your code:

```
return foos.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getSetId, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a hashmap, it should handle hashing for you to bring your runtime down to near linear.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by ernest_k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60254281/642706) is correct and clear. Here is more code, a full example.

First, define a class for `Person`.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Person
{
    // ----------|  Member fields  |----------------------
    public String name;
    public LocalDate birthdate;

    // ----------|  Constructor  |----------------------
    public Person ( String name , LocalDate birthdate )
    {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        this.birthdate = Objects.requireNonNull( birthdate );
    }

    // ----------|  Object  |----------------------

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | birthdate=" + birthdate +
                " }";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Person person = ( Person ) o;
        return name.equals( person.name ) &&
                birthdate.equals( person.birthdate );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , birthdate );
    }
}
```

Populate some sample data. The `Set.of` syntax added to Java 9 gives us simple literals syntax.

```
Set < Person > persons = Set.of(
        new Person( "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 1990 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ,
        new Person( "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.FEBRUARY , 24 ) ) ,
        new Person( "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 1990 , Month.MARCH , 25 ) )
);
```

### Concurrency

Define the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) we want to populate. You mentioned concurrency as an issue, that is, sharing this map across threads. So we should use one of the two classes bundled with Java that implement the [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) interface.

Here is a graphic table I made showing the attributes of the various `Map` implementations bundled with Java.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features.]

Here we choose to use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). The alternative, [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) might be better if you had large numbers of objects, or if you wanted to maintain the keys ([`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) in our case) in a certain order.

```
Map < Year, List < Person > > yearToListOfPersonsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap <>();
```

### Data types

Notice the appropriate use of data types. Java offers a [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class to represent an entire year. So we should use it. Doing so makes our code more self-documenting.

On the `Person` class, we represent a birth date using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). That class is for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Multimap

We will extract the year from each person’s birthdate as the key to our map. The value is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of `Person` objects, to which we add the person object in question.

If you wanted to eliminate any possible duplicate `Person` objects from being collected, you could use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) here rather than a `List`.

The [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method added in Java 8 does the work of what is known as a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), a map where a key leads to a collection of values rather than a single value. Alternatively, you could use a multipmap implementation from a third-party such as the [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library.

```
for ( Person person : persons )
{
    yearToListOfPersonsMap.computeIfAbsent(
            Year.from( person.birthdate ) ,
            ( ( Year key ) -> new ArrayList <>() )
    ).add( person )
    ;
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "yearToListOfPersonsMap = " + yearToListOfPersonsMap );
```

> yearToListOfPersonsMap = {2000=[Person{ name='Bob' | birthdate=2000-02-24 }], 1990=[Person{ name='Alice' | birthdate=1990-01-23 }, Person{ name='Carol' | birthdate=1990-03-25 }]}